# ARM64 inline assembly BL BLR BR instructions

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, arm64

I am in the middle of a problem that I can't seem to figure out. It involves testing the instruction set using c++ and inline assembly for the arm64. My current problems are with BL, BLR and the BR instructions. My current code looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LDRARRAYLENGTH   (4)

__asm __volatile
(
    ".global  myFunction               \n\t"
    ".p2align 4                        \n\t"
    ".type    myFunction,%function     \n\t"
    "myFunction:                       \n\t"
           "mov  x0, #10               \n\t"
           "ret   x30                     \n\t"

);

/*
 *
 */
bool BranchingModes(void)
{
    bool BranchingModesFlag = false;

    //local registers
    int regw0 = 0x00;
    int regw1 = 0x00;
    int regw2 = 0x00;
    int regw3 = 0x00;

    /*
     * Branch with Link branches to a PC-relative offset, setting
     * the register X30 to PC+4. It provides a hint that this is a
     * subroutine call.
     */
    //Clear variables
    regw0 = 0x00;
    regw1 = 0x00;
    regw2 = 0x00;
    regw3 = 0x00;

    __asm __volatile
    (
        "mov  x0, #0                        \n\t"     /* setting up initial variable a */
        "bl myFunction                      \n\t"
        "mov  %[reg1],  x0                  \n\t"
        "nop                                \n\t"

        :[reg0] "=r"(regw0), [reg1] "=r"(regw1)
        :/* This is an empty input operand list */
    );

    /*
     * The BL instruction calls a subroutine called myFunction within the subroutine
     * a variable/register gets a value of 10. When the subroutine returns the
     * the variable/register that got populated in the subroutine gets copied
     * to another variable/register to acknowledge that the subroutine got called
     * and returned using the BL instruction
     */
    if((regw0 == 10) && (regw1 == 10))
    {
        BranchingModesFlag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        BranchingModesFlag = false;
    }

    return BranchingModesFlag;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int i0 = 0x00;
    unsigned int counter = 0x00;

    BranchingModes();

    for(i0=0x00; i0<=10000;  i0++)
    {
        counter = counter  + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Issue is the code doesn't seem to make to the for loop after BranchingModes function. I know it's the asm section of the BranchingModes function which utilizes the BL instruction.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong with that instruction. Am I returning correctly out of the "myFunction" using "ret x30"? I have attempted to use "BR x30" with no success. As BL updates "PC+4" and gets sorted to x30.  Similar issue with the BLR instruction, I would appreciate any insight with my issues.

Comment: Many modern compilers no longer permit inline asm. Just saying.

Comment: The code that I have posted is trimmed down just wanted to show the code segment where my issue.  But I have numerous  asm calls through out with no problems. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @JesperJuhl only msvc has difficulties with inline assembly. Both clang and gcc have production quality inline assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler about all registers you clobber, but you don't. The compiler doesn't see your changes to `x0` and `x30`, the latter of which is presumably the reason why your program never returns from `BranchingModes`.

Haven't tested it, but this should work:

```c
__asm __volatile
(
    "mov  x0, #0                        \n\t"     /* setting up initial variable a */
    "bl myFunction                      \n\t"
    "mov  %[reg1],  x0                  \n\t"
    "nop                                \n\t"

    :[reg0] "=r"(regw0), [reg1] "=r"(regw1)
    :/* This is an empty input operand list */
    :"x0", "x30"
);
```

Note that this is for calling your specific function. For arbitrary ABI-compliant functions, you'll need to list everything the ABI specifies to be caller-saved as clobber. This will usually be `x0` through `x18` plus `x30`, `d8` through `d15`, as well as `cc` and `memory`.

Comment: Siguza, Thank you so very much that was my source of error.